# How to add web cam(video) recording as overlay using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, webcam, recording, screen-recorder

I have created following command to overlay image in video (desktop recording ):

```
C:\>ffmpeg -y -rtbufsize 100M -f gdigrab -framerate 20 -offset_x 0 -offset_y 0 -video_size 1250x750 -draw_mouse 1 -i desktop -f dshow -i audio="Microphone (High
 Definition Audio Device)" -c:v libx264 -r 20 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -crf 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a libmp3lame -qscale:a 4 "D:\today.mp4"  -i "C:\My.jpg"  -filter_complex "pad=height=ih+10:color=black,overlay=(main_w-overlay_w):main_h-overlay_h"
```

And able to see expected result, but when I am using my web cam as

```
video="HP Truevision HD"
```

instead of image file, i am getting error as its trying to find image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -y -rtbufsize 100M -f gdigrab -framerate 20 -offset_x 0 -offset_y 0
       -video_size 1250x750 -draw_mouse 1 -i desktop
       -f dshow -i video="HP Truevision HD":audio="Microphone (High Definition Audio Device)"
       -filter_complex "[0]pad=height=ih+10:color=black[b];
                        [b][1:v]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w):main_h-overlay_h[v]" -map "[v]"
       -c:v libx264 -r 20 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -crf 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p
       -map 1:a -c:a libmp3lame -qscale:a 4 "D:\today.mp4"
```

Comment: Thanks @Malvya, there seems frame-rate issue but I will fix it now. Will let you know.

Comment: Hi @Malvya, its bit difficult to understand ffmpeg command as I spend a week to figure out the frame rate latency (in overlay) and scale overlay video with no success. could you please help me in this.

Comment: lots of errors.

Comment: @chovy Such as?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I do:

```
#!/bin/env zsh

file=`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S`
ffmpeg -f alsa -i pulse -f x11grab -thread_queue_size 64 -i :0.0 -i /dev/video0 \
       -filter_complex 'overlay=main_w-overlay_w:main_h-overlay_h' \
    -r 60 -preset ultrafast ~/Videos/screencast-${file}.mp4
```

One thing I'm trying to figure out is how to scale down the camera size.

Comment: 1) x11grab default frame rate is 30000/1001 (aka "29.97"). So if you want 60 fps remove `-r 60` and use `-framerate 60` input option (before `-i :0.0`). Otherwise, with your current command, it will just duplicate frames to reach 60. 2) *"I'm trying to figure out is how to scale down the camera size"* Use the scale filter: `[2]scale=iw/2:-1[cam];[1][cam]overlay=main_w-overlay_w:main_h-overlay_h`. 3) You may need to add `-f v4l2` before `-i /dev/video0`.

Comment: What does the `-f v412` do?